# Non-editable rows in Primeface's treeTable

Tags: primefaces

I am using Primeface's [TreeTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/edit.xhtml), and I need only some rows to be editable (lowest level) and others to be non-editable. I have properties of article and they are categorized - so categories should NOT be editable and properties should be editable. Something like

```
1. Category 1     <- noneditable
 1.1. Property 1  <- editable
 1.2. Property 2  <- editable
2. Category 2     <- noneditable
 2.1. Property 3  <- editable
 2.2. Property 4  <- editable
```

Tried to google it, but can't find solution for rows, only for columns.

Thaks in advance.

Comment: my first idea is to set a column and name it "Action" it mean the action that you can do in your row and set some commandbutton in this column and make them editable or not (with a condition) but it's not the solution that you want to read, i am working on it to see if it's possible

Comment: Which version of PrimeFaces are you using? What does the solution for columns you found look like? Are you not able to adapt that to rows? What else have you tried so far? How should the rows be edited? Full row edit, in cell edit or is a button (like @YagamiLight suggested) with popup solution conceivable?

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I am using Primefaces 6.0. Solution for colums is about providing `<p:cellEditor>` or not. For my purposes I prefer rows to be edited inline using `<p:rowEditor />` so full row edit. Anyway I was looking for some build-in solution, but catn't find any, so I will go Yagami's way.